# SSL on Namecheap, Node and Heroku

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, namecheap

I am very confused about how to get SSL on my Namecheap domain running Heroku running Node.js. I purchased a domain from Namecheap.com and at the same time purchased

```
positivessl
Comodo SSL Certificate for www.xxx.com
```

In order to run through the process it had me use a portion of their portal that generated a CSR code. The applet that generated this CSR code also generated the contents of .key and .cert files, so I saved those somewhere [I think these are self signed, and I *don't* need them]. Then a few minutes later **Sectigo Certification Authority** sent me a package with

```
website.ca-bundle
website.crt
```

`Namecheap` provided a link that also had these files plus

```
website.p7b
```

Soo.. now i have 6 files in total..!

```
website.cert <- generated from CSR generator
website.csr <- generated from CSR generator
website.key <- generated from CSR generator
website.crt <- generated from Sectigo Certification Authority
website.ca-bundle <- generated from Sectigo Certification Authority
website.p7b <- generated from Namecheap (??)
```

Now testing locally in Node.js I am able to do the following configurations

Configuration one using the cert/key from the CSR generator applet.

```
let options = {
    key: "website.key", 
    cert: "website.cert"
};
let server = Https.createServer(options, listener);
```

When I runs this, I must go to `https://localhost:80` and I get the whole "not secure" business, and I accept the warning and the site loads. When I inspect the cert it says "Invalid" and that it is issued by wwww.xxx.com.

Configuration two using the files sent to me by Sectigo/Namecheap.

```
let options = {
    key: "website.key", 
    cert: "website.crt",
    ca: "website.ca-bundle "
};
let server = Https.createServer(options, listener);
```

Same as above, but when I inspect the cert it says that it is issued by Sectigo. Also I am *assuming* that the browser says it's "Invalid: because I am not accessing the cert through my domain. Fair enough.

SO. Now I am unsure how to get this to work with Heroku. They have the annoying language that SSL is "free" for "paid" dynos (...) but that you can use a "manual" option using the CLI. I have spent a few hours around this area and I don't know what to do. At the present, going to my heroku app through my domain simply "This site can’t provide a secure connection". While I think my Node setup is correct, I don't think I know what to do with Heroku at this point. Do I need to get these certs *into* Heroku somehow?

---

The things I've been poking at from the Heroku level is

`heroku cert` commands and I also see in their guide about DNS setup this example

```
CNAME   examplesecure   example-12345.ssl.herokudns.com.
```

But I don't know where to get that ssl dns domain from..

Answer (score 1):

Call namecheap support and make them do everystep for you. Dont even think. You payed money. I had same issue. Node/SSL/Heroku/NameCheap. Same issue, support agent helped me to the end with details.

Comment: OK!.. I will try.

Answer (score -1):

Well go over the public and secret keys and if it checks out on your hosting server (i used heroku) you could use an ssl checker like this one [SSL CHECKER](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html). If it doesn't check out then you have to go back to the keys. The namecheap support are quite fast so they'll sort you out. On the other hand if is check out with the ssl checker then you have to force your app to use ssl. This link should help[link to heroku salesforce](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls). If nothing is working still my guess is you've been at it for a while and you need to rest and bring fresh eyes. May the force be with you.